# Append Column Name while Initializing Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I initialize the following pandas Dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A,'B'])
```

Now, I would like to append yet another column name 'C'.

How can I do that?

**Expected result:**

The result should be the same as if I would have done directly

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A,'B','C'])
```

(For programming reasons I cannot do it directly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may add a column and set it to None:

```
df['C'] = None
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Do with `reindex`

```
df=df.reindex(columns=df.columns.tolist()+['C'])
df
Out[410]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []
```

Or

```
df.insert(loc=df.shape[1], column='C',value=None)
df
Out[413]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A, B, C]
Index: []
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simple. You can either do,

```
df['C'] = <list_of_values>
```

or,

```
df.insert(<which_position_to_insert>,<column_name>,<list_of_values>,<True_or_False>)
```

The `True_or_False` parameter in the `insert()` function is to mention whether you want to include duplicate values or not.